# Convert ASP code using Chr(13) to PHP

Tags: php, asp-classic

I am trying to move a old Classic ASP site to run in PHP. I am rewriting bits of it, however I have come across the following function that is causing me some problems. Basically the function `FixForSQL` is run on everything before adding it to the database and then `FixForHTML` is run on data returned with a SQL query to format it for display.

At the moment if I display a block of text retrieved from the database in PHP it shows as one huge block of text with no paragraph breaks, I presume because I haven't done the replace of `Chr(13)` and whatever `Chr(9)` is!

Does anyone know how to reproduce whatever is happening in PHP 5?

```
 Function FixForHTML(tmpText1)
    Dim tmpText2
    tmpText2 = tmpText1
    tmpText2 = Replace(tmpText2,Chr(13),"</p><p>" & vbCrLf)
    tmpText2 = Replace(tmpText2,Chr(9),"&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;")
    FixForHTML = tmpText2
 End Function

 Function FixForSQL(tmpText1)
    Dim tmpText2
    tmpText2 = tmpText1
    tmpText2 = Replace(tmpText1,vbCrLf,Chr(13))
    tmpText2 = Replace(tmpText2,Chr(39),String(2,39))
    FixForSQL = tmpText2
 End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Chr(13)` is the the character whose ASCII code is 13. You can get it in PHP with, you guessed, `chr(13)`.

`13` is the code for *Cariage return*. While `9` is for *Horizontal tab*. In PHP you can also get those characters in a parsable string (one delimited by `"`s) with `\n`, respectively `\t`.

[ASCII table](http://www.hobbyprojects.com/ascii-table/images/ascii-table1.gif)

Sample code for PHP:

```
$text = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), array("</p><p>", "&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;"), $text);
```

---

As for the `FixForSQL` function, it just replaces `'` characters with `''` to escape them for the SQL query.